# Let $f(x)$ be a quadratic with nonreal roots. Show that if the coefficient of $x^2$ in $f(x)$ is positive, then $f(x)>0$ for all $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

I do not understand the solution the book gives:

"Completing the square gives $f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$ for some constants $h$ and $k$. The roots of $f(x)$ are the solutions to the equation $a(x-h)^2+k=0$. Rearranging this equation gives $(x-h)^2=-k/a$. We are given that $a>0$ and that the roots of $f(x)$ are nonreal. So, we must have $k>0$, as well. Since $k>0$ and $a(x-h)^2\geq0$ for all $x$, we have $f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k\gt0$ for all $x$."

Can someone please explain this solution in more detail, especially the deductions made?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain *what* you don't find clear? It's a pretty explicit solution - what part do you need in more detail?

Comment: As $x$ takes real values, $(x-h)^2$ takes all non-negative real vales for any given $h$, so if $k\leqslant0$, you will always get real roots. All the rest seems explicit.

Comment: A simpler proof would be to use continuity directly on $f(x)$.  As the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive, for large enough $x$ we must have $f(x)>0$. Then if $f(x)\leqslant 0 $ somewhere, then the function must cross the $X$ axis somewhere, i.e. there are real roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First complete the square. The roots $r_0, r_1$ are those complex numbers such that $a(r_0 - h)^2 + k = 0$ and $a(r_1 - h)^2 + k = 0$. Rearranging, we get $(r - h)^2 = -k/a$, which implies $r = h \pm \sqrt{-k/a}$.

We know the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive, i.e. $a$ is positive. Now notice that we are given that $r$ is non-real, hence we must have $-k/a$ being negative. Hence, $k$ must be positive.

Now, we have $a > 0$, and we know $(x-h)^2 \geq 0$ since it is the square of a real number (we assume $x$ is real), and $k > 0$. Hence, $a(x-h)^2 + k$ is greater than zero.

Comment: I think that the part which I am confused about is why r being nonreal implies that -k/a is negative (I feel like there is something very obvious which I just cannot remember)

Comment: If $-\dfrac{k}{a}$ is positive, then we can solve $(x-h)^2 = -\dfrac{k}{a}$ in real numbers: $x = h \pm \sqrt{-\dfrac{k}{a}}$ - the key is square root of a negative number is not real.

Answer (score 2):

We can do it slightly differently using the old form: $f(x) = ax^2+bx +c$ with $a > 0$. The condition that $f$ has non-real roots implies $b^2-4ac < 0$. By completing square, we have: $f(x) = a\left(x+\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)^2+ \dfrac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\geq \dfrac{4ac-b^2}{4a} > 0$.